iCloud downloads unknown data
iCloud sporadically synchronizes more than 12GB data, although all folders are selected with "remove Download". To be sure that every single file in my iCloud is removed as download i ran this command:
cd Library/Mobile\ Documents/com\~apple\~CloudDocs/; find . -type f -exec brctl evict {} \;

iCloud Drive Setting is iCloud Drive On and also Optimize iCloud Storage On. Synch Desktop and Documents is turned off.
In Storage iCloud Drive shows, that it uses 40,1MB.

How can I track what 12.75GB (8 Files) of data is iCloud downloading?
EDIT 1: If I switch iCloud Drive off, the download stops. As soon as I turn iCloud Drive on again, it synchronizes the data at different times and on different days, sometimes several times a day.
